# Creating alert message

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create my own simple alert dialog with jQuery. Two problems: how do I disallow people to click on any elements in body before user clicks OK button in alert? And, how to make  body all dark except one element? Thanks.

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place a div with partial opacity over all content. Typical CSS:

```
.cover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  opacity: .7;
  background-color: #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Now place a positioned div, the dialog box, over the .cover div, and give this dialog a higher z-index.

Comment: This is really all it takes; the difficulty comes in making it cross-browser compatible; select elements may still appear on top, same as any `object` embeds (like Flash player), etc.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than reinventing the wheel, I'd look at [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal) with the modal option.

Comment: Too heavy, I believe I can write it in a few lines.

Comment: @hey Why not look at the jQuery UI dialogue source code and trim it down to only have the features you need?

Comment: @hey Well, why are you asking this question then?

Comment: I'm sure it can be done, I don't know about "a few lines" though. I'd be interested to see what you come up with.

Comment: Should be possible in relatively few lines, certainly fewer than the more generic plugin, if using assumptions like always modal, always one button, etc. (i.e., if building a direct replacement for a standard `window.alert()`).